# phonegap inappbrowser IOS not working

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I created a project in phonegap for IOS and I want to open a ulr in my IOS browser but not inside my app. I tried to use inAppBrowser plugin but it seems it doesn't to working. 


I only use `.html, .css, .js files and the config.xml` and I am on Windows and I build my project with online tool `Adobe Phonegap builder`

If I get it right, according to this link `https: build.phonegap.com/plugins/658` there is no need to install the plugin you want to use, as some suggest with the command `cordova plugin add...`. You can have your job done by reffering the plugin inside the `config.xml` file. Am I right?


My config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns = " www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = " phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id    = "com.test.testingApp"
    version   = "1.0.0">

    <name>test</name>

    <!-- app icons and splashscreen -->
    <icon src="icon.png" /> 
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/android/icon-48-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/android/icon-96-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/android/icon-144-hdpi.png" />

        <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" src="splash.png" width="320" height="470" />
        <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" src="splash.png" width="480" height="640" />
        <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" src="splash.png" width="720" height="960" />
        <gap:splash gap:density="xxhdpi" src="splash.png" />
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    </platform>


    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />



    <!-- splashscreen delay -->
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" /> 

    <access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>

    <!-- <content src=" mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->
    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />

    <!-- <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" /> -->

  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
    <!--
  <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
  <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
  <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="keepRunning" value="false" />
    --> 

    <feature name="App">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <!--
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    -->
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <!--
    <feature name="Storage">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    -->
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <!--
    <feature name="Echo">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    -->
    <feature name="InAppBrowser"> 
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" /> 
    </feature>

    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
    <plugins>
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.3.3" />
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

My index.html file is:

```
<html> 
<head>      
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta id="extViewportMeta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova_plugins.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="  code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"> 
    <script src="  code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="  code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<div data-role="page">

    <!-- MAIN BODY -->
    <div data-role="content" role="main" style="padding-bottom:230px;">
        <div class="main_header">
                    <br />      
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.open(' www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes'); return false;">PlanTech</a>
                    <br />      
                    <a href="#" onclick="window.open(' www.google.com', '_system', 'location=no');return false; ">PlanTech</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="highlight"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that both links open inside my app (and not in a separate browser as they supposed to). As a result, there is no chance to get back to my `index.html` page after one of the links is clicked without ending the app and restarting it. 
I would appreciate it if someone could help me go through this, because I searched several times the internet and I am stuck.

Thanks in advance everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my question myself. As usual it was in front of my eyes, but I would find it not in a thousand years if I wasn't lucky enough to see it.

As the `config.xml` itself suggests: `<!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->`

So I had to change the following code

```
<plugins>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.3.3" />
</plugins>
```

with THIS:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.3.3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this `... there is no chance to get back to my index.html page after one of the links clicked`

If you go through complete [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser),

1 - Return the window object like

```
     var ref = window.open ('www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

2 - Add an event listener for exit event.

```
    ref.addEventListener(exit, myexitcallback);
```

3 - close method will close the browser window. So, in your function call back  :

```
function myexitcallback{
   ref.close();
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.
Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't solved my problem. The link still opens inside my app and not as a separate app as it should. And of course there is no back button or something similar that indicates a return in my app without the need to exit it first.
So I still have doubds `if reffering the plugin in config.xml is enough for the online builder to install the inAppBrowser plugin in my app`